# Spring, Summer, Fall, Winter... and Spring

Tags: translation

The movie [Spring, Summer, Fall, Winter... and Spring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwCHBJYOi5E&t=2360) is full of symbolism, and I searched for them, and I found many of the answers. There are three writings that I am curious about their meaning. I don't know whether they were written in Korean or Japanese.

From minutes 39:20 to 39:45 the master writes something with water on the stone, but I don't know the meaning of the writings. Whatever they are, they are probably referring to futile work. You can see the images here.

[image]
[image]
[image]

When the master sits on the boat before his death, he covers his eyes his mouth with some writings which I do not know.

[image]

Also, in another scene, he writes some sutras [Heart Sutra] on the monastery deck, for which again I do not have any idea.

What is the translation of those scentences?

Comment: 1. I suppose that he was thinking to write "飛流直下三千尺 疑是銀河...." This is part of ["望廬山瀑布"](https://chinesepoemsinenglish.blogspot.com/2009/09/li-bai-view-of-waterfall-at-lushan.html), a Chinese poem. 2. The letter 閉 means to shut or close.

Comment: @Klmo Thank you so much for your help, this gives me a very good clue to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. 비류직하삼천척 (飛流直下三千尺)

> - 飛流 直下 三千尺
> - 비류 직하 삼천척

- 물줄기(비류)가 '삼천 척'을 수'직하'강하다.
- 이백(李白)의 한시 망여산폭포(望廬山瀑布)의 한 구절입니다.
- 시원하게 떨어지는 폭포수를 묘사한 표현이에요.

### 2. 폐 (閉)

`閉`는 `닫을 폐` 자고 `폐쇄`의 `폐`입니다.

### 3. 반야심경 (般若思想)

반야심경은 한국에서 가장 대표적인 불교 경전입니다. 내용은 대충 검색하면 나옵니다.

- https://ko.wikisource.org/wiki/%EB%B2%88%EC%97%AD:%EB%B0%98%EC%95%BC%EB%B0%94%EB%9D%BC%EB%B0%80%EB%8B%A4%EC%8B%AC%EA%B2%BD
- http://encykorea.aks.ac.kr/Contents/Item/E0021513

> 영화에서는 제자가 사찰로 돌아왔을 때 노승이 고양이 꼬리로 마룻바닥에 반야심경을 적습니다. 그리고 제자가 살인을 저지른 그 칼로 바닥에 적힌 글자를 따라 새기게 합니다.

첨부한 사진은 영화의 한 장면인데, 반야심경 맨 앞 구절부터 끝까지를 스님이 순서대로 따라 적고 있는 것처럼 보입니다.

- 摩訶般若波羅蜜多心經 觀自在菩薩 ...
- 마하반야바라밀다심경 관자재보살 ...

[image: 봄여름가을겨울그리고봄반야심경]

Answer (score 1):

Wow, you saw Spring, Summer, Fall, Winter... and Spring.
It's a controversial and difficult movie. so even critics have several opinion.
so, my answer is not perfect.

first question, at 39:20~39:45, master write buddhist scriptures.
it`s talk about desire . but that`s scriptures write with water, so it`s disappear very fast and easy.
when it erase, master write again and again. it show us The fleeting of desire.

second question, the cover letter is Chinese character. that letter mean "close"

third question, Heart Sutra mean most famous buddhist scripture. but there`s no picture so i cannot translate it.

Comment: Thank you so much for you, I didn't understand your answer to the first question. Is it something related to "desire"?

Comment: @Davood KHAJEHPOUR Content is not important.You can compare the act of writing to desire.
When you eat delicious food, you feel pleasure at first.
But over time, the pleasure disappears.
(Like Buddhist scriptures written in water)
This scene can also be related to the second picture.
The letters in the second scene mean closed.
When you feel pleasure, you perceive it with your senses (eyes, nose, mouth, ears).
But even a master couldn't premiere in all desires.
Therefore, he committed suicide by blocking all the sense organs in order not to lose his desire even at the last minute.

Comment: @DavoodKHAJEHPOUR I know this is hindering your interpretation, but I thought you needed this explanation to explain these scenes. I'm very sorry if I interfered with your interpretation.